# google map pointer Move on the updated data for mysql on every after 10 sec

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

> this is getting data latlong

```
<?php
      $queryForRiders = 'SELECT R.RiderName , AR.CurrentLatitude, 
                        AR.CurrentLongitude, C.CityName, 
                        AR.LastUpdateDateTime, V.VehicleRegisteration , 
                        AR.RiderDevice_Id
                    FROM `call_dakaar`.`activeriders` AR

            LEFT JOIN `call_dakaar`.`rider` R ON AR.Rider_Id = R.Rider_Id
            LEFT JOIN `call_dakaar`.`city` C ON AR.City_Id = C.City_Id
            LEFT JOIN `call_dakaar`.`vehicle` V ON AR.Vehicle_Id = V.Vehicle_Id';

      $activeRiders = $pdo->query($queryForRiders);
      //$data  = $activeRiders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      while ($row  = $activeRiders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


          $rider_name = $row['RiderName'];
          $longitude  = $row['CurrentLongitude'];
          $latitude = $row['CurrentLatitude'];
          $locations[]=array( $rider_name, $latitude, $longitude );

      }
      $markers = json_encode( $locations );

?>
```

> JQuery function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#map').height($('.page-container').height());
        $( window ).resize(function() {
            $('#map').height($('.page-container').height());
        });
        <?php
        echo "var markers=$markers;\n";
        ?>
```

> Initialize Map

```
        map = new GMaps({
            el: '#map',
            lat: 24.8615,
            lng: 67.0099,
            zoom: 12,
            zoomControl : true,
            zoomControlOpt: {
                style : 'SMALL',
                position: 'TOP_LEFT'
            },
            circleOptions: {
                fillColor: '#ffff00',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                clickable: false,
                editable: true,
                zIndex: 1
            },
            panControl : false,
            streetViewControl : false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
    var i = 0;
        setInterval( function(){
            map.addMarker({
                lat: markers[i][1],
                lng: markers[i][2],
                icon: 'http://calldakaar.com/dashboard/assets/images/admin/bike.png',
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                draggable:true,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });
            i += 1;
        },100);
```

Comment: And what may we ask is your question.

Comment: after 10 sec i want to move my marker according to updated data  of table

Answer (score 0):

You should set lat lng values every 10 sec in your map object. Then you can call your php script using something like this,

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "path to your php script",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',  
            success: function (result) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(result) ;

                // set values to marker 
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
```

and

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(obj[i][1], obj[i][2]),
         map: map
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ,
but i m still unable to add market on the map by doing your method

Comment: and mine 
   var obj =  JSON.parse(result) ;
                    var i = 0;
                        map.addMarker({
                            lat: obj[i][1],
                            lng: obj[i][2],
                            icon: 'http://calldakaar.com/dashboard/assets/images/admin/bike.png',
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                            draggable:true,
                            title: obj[i][0]
                        });
                        i += 1;